# how do i export face normals?

Tags: export, csv

Is it possible to retrieve the vertices's of every face in a mesh?

Also is it possible to get the normals of those faces?

I want to store them in a csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [mesh objects data](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Mesh.html) contains lists for [`vertices`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.MeshVertex.html), [`edges`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.MeshEdge.html) and [`polygons`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.MeshPolygon.html). Each edge and polygon has a list of vertex indices that it uses.

Python's [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) is included with blender's python install.

```
import bpy
import csv

obj_data = bpy.context.active_object.data

with open('out.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    data = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for f in obj_data.polygons:
        face_data = []
        for i in f.vertices:
            face_data += [obj_data.vertices[i].co]
        face_data += [f.normal]
        data.writerow(face_data)
```

Comment: how do i get rid of the vector part? "<Vector (-0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000)>"

Comment: A vector is a list containing three numbers, you can access each number directly `f.normal[0], f.normal[1], f.normal[2]` to stop the vector describing itself.